# Search for matching values in a table and replace with array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I want to loop through my table, compare the values of a column with a list of array values so that if there's a match, i replace the value in the table with the array keys.
Ideally, i could have done it this way(search/replace) but i have a whole lot of values. So I want to include the array in an inc file.

```
while($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
            $fields_count = 0;
            foreach($row as $key => $val){
                if($fields_count++ > 0)
                $val = str_replace("Appliances > Air Conditioners","111,233", $val);
                $val = str_replace("Appliances > Air Purifiers","154,234", $val);
                $val = str_replace("Appliances > Appliance Accessories > Air Conditioner Accessories","123,235", $val);
```

this is my array and keys, how do i get my loop done, so that i can search for matching values in the array and replace them with the array keys in my table?

```
$arr_categories = array( 
    "111,233"=>"Appliances > Air Conditioners",
    "154,234"=>"Appliances > Air Purifiers",
    "123,235"=>"Appliances > Appliance Accessories > Air Conditioner Accessories");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrCategories = array( 
    '111,233' => 'Appliances > Air Conditioners',
    '154,234' => 'Appliances > Air Purifiers',
    '123,235' => 'Appliances > Appliance Accessories > Air Conditioner Accessories'
);

while ($row = $db->fetchAssoc()) {
    foreach ($row as &$column) {
        foreach ($arrCategories as $key => $category) {
            $column = str_replace($category, $key, $column);
        }
    }

    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ moteutch: I'm trying out now

Comment: @mouteutsch: Still missing something here.. my table column name is CatID. can u relate it to my code? thanks man